# How to create GridView in ASP.NET with Horizontal Scroll but 2 first columns are fixed

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to create a Gridview with columns ID, Name and 20 other columns. So it overflow and I need use scroll but ID and Name are fixed.

Comment: Do you want your GridView to be in place editable with edit templates or you just want to show data only ?

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean you want fixed header and freeze some column?
If yes, i wrote jQuery plug-in can do this!

[image]

look the website: http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/

Supported Browsers

- Internet Explorer 7, 8 (IE 9 Compatibility)
- Internet Explorer 9 (9.0.8112)
- Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 7 Preview
- Google Chrome(23.0.1271.64 m)
- Mozilla Firefox (16.0.2)
- Apple Safari (5.1.7)